# asp.net mschart X axis show 12 hour time format

Tags: asp.net, mschart

How to show time in 12 hours format 1-12 AM and 1-12 PM together on X axis of MS chart control.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this property

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "t";
```

Check the formats here

[DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)